# Method with non-zero RVA in import

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, exception, obfuscation

I'm not even sure of what happened, the project was working fine on Visual Studio, I just updated some images and labels for a newer splash screen, generated, obfucasted code, created the installer and when I tried to run the program I would randomly get that exception, it has never happened before, what is it about? There's not much info about it online.

Actually the only thing I did notice was that the installer was a bit bigger than it's usual size, about 40% bigger file actually (it´s not that big).

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the error, such as a stack trace?

Comment: I'm affraid maybe not, I think the error made itself while obfucasting the project's dlls, for some reason some even doubled its size, it's never happened to me before, I replaced them with the originals and the program worked as usual. Thanks for the comment though, I seem to remember a certain @StevenDoggart helping me with some questions about a year ago. ;)